# find most recent date with unique reference excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data (I can't sort, filter or delete it as its used by others) where I want to find the most recent date per account. 20,000 lines of data.

I've used this formula in column C

```
=IF(MAX(IF($B$2:$B$16=B2,$A$2:$A$16))=A2,"Yes","no")
```

However it looks at all the data in column B, it doesn't identify the unique accounts. There should be another Yes in cell C3

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

[image]

Comment: You could try using dynamic arrays, a combination of `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array formula (ctrl + shift + enter) like this one:

`=IF(MAX(($A$2:$A$16)*($B$2:$B$16=$B2))=A2,"Yes","No")`

Explanation:

```py
=IF(
  MAX( # gets max date in the range
    ($A$2:$A$16) * ($B$2:$B$16=$B2)
    # if the value in B matches, it will return the date (date * 1), otherwise 0 (date * 0)
  )=A2, # if max date is the same as the date in current row
  "Yes", # then return "yes"
  "No" # otherwise return "no"
)
```

Comment: Taking the product of the ranges works for `MAX`, but I can easily imagine someone wanting to take your formula and replace `MAX` with `MIN`, which of course will fail in your case, though not for the version `=IF(MAX(IF($B$2:$B$7=$B2,$A$2:$A$7))=A2,"Yes","No")`. In general, it's preferable to use recursive `IF` statements rather than taking the product of conditional clauses, since Boolean `FALSE`s are ignored by `MIN`, whereas zeroes are not.

Comment: This worked on 1 spreadsheet i had, for another one it didn't. This is the solution. The new challenge is to find out why it doesn't work on other workbooks - thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have `MAXIFS()`?

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(A2=MAXIFS(A$2:A$7,B$2:B$7,B2),"Yes","No")
```

Or, with ms365:

```
=IF(A2:A7=MAXIFS(A2:A7,B2:B7,B2:B7),"Yes","No")
```

---

A much better solution may be to look into a PivotTable and use the 'Account' for rows and 'Date' as values where you'd only choose to show the max.

Comment: i'm working with excel 2013 so i don't have these very useful functions. I tried them on excel 365 at home - both worked. thanks very much